# z-index stacking issue with React fullpage.js

Tags: css, reactjs, z-index, fullpage.js

Check demo here: https://p6msv.csb.app/

I cannot figure out how to get this 'more info' modal to sit above all other elements on the screen.

the following is the desired stacking order, first being the highest stacked element:

- modal
- nav open
- header
- fullpage.js section

Anyone see something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite sure understand your problem but for the modal consider using the fullpage.js option `normalScrollElements` or even disabling the whole fullPage.js scroll when opening it by using `fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false)`.

Also, any fixed element should be placed outside the fullPage.js wrapper. This is a bug in a few browsers when dealing with 3d css transforms.

If you can't move it for some reason, you can try using  the `fixedElements` option or even moving away from 3d transformations by using `scrollBar:true` or `css3: false`.

More about all these options and methods on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is as follows: if you open my demo and click the 'more info' button a modal will pop up. the top of that modal is currently underneath the header. I would like that modal to sit over top of all elements on the page to give a fullscreen effect.

Comment: Just position it fixed then? Use the CSS propertly `position: fixed`

Comment: the header is already set to position fixed. I'm having a z-index issue, my header z-index is set to 1 but when I add z-index > 1 to the modal container, nothing happens. 

This is how I want each element to sit on the page:
modal = z-index: 2
header = z-index: 1
fullpage.js section = z-index: 0

the modal is set to position absolute but adding z-index does not affect anything.

Comment: Place them outside the fullpage wrapper